# NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have Problems with coding in Swift.

I want to parse a JSON String but I get this Error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value for key in object around character 8." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value for key in object around character 8.}
```

I don't know, how to handle this error. All error messages in Swift are unintelligible for me. Errors in other language are much easier.

My Code:

```
let jsonString = "{\"name:\"fred\", \"age\":40}"
    let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    do {
        let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
        print(parsed)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. Fix it

check your json here

http://jsonlint.com/

try this

```
"{\"name\":\"Fred\",\"age\":\"40\"}"
```

Comment: OMG, sorry. That's a fail.. -.- Thank you.